# In Azure, how to I set Shared Access Signatures to expire within 1 hour

Tags: azure, azure-storage

On the shared access page, the Start and expiry date/time fields are 8 hours apart. Currently they show: Start = 11:22:27 AM, End = 7:22:27 PM.

I need to set these 59 minutes apart. My instructions say to change the fields using the calendar picker but this just reverts to whatever was there already.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried setting the date using the calendar picker and manually type in the time to whatever you need ? What is the error you get when doing this?

Comment: Yes, I've tried exactly that. The problem is that is sets the start date/time to whenever I enter the screen and the end date to that + 8 hours.

Comment: 8 hours is the default and this is what Azure will set each time you enter the SAS screen. You need to set the expiry to what you need and click the generate SAS button to actually get the SAS which you will use. The next time you enter the screen, it will again be 8 hours for you to generate a new SAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

When you change it by hand at times end it will change to original as below:

[image]

Then I changed with Calander and it changed according to my wish that is 1 hour as below:

[image]

SAS got created as below:

[image]

Comment: I suppose what I'm needing to know is how to set the default to 1 hour instead of 8.

Comment: By Default its set to 8 hrs, if you want to change by 1 hr, you need to do in above way. There many ways to change it. But default is 8 hrs